# JavaScript Reduce array on timestamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am trying to reduce this array based on the timestamp:

```
Var Data = [{"Group":"OPS","Date":"2017-04-18T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"BOE","Date":"2017-04-19T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"EDW","Date":"2017-04-21T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"SUPPORT","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"EDWEXTRACTS","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"EDWEXTRACTS","Date":"2017-04-18T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"SAFTT","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"SAFTT","Date":"2017-04-18T00:00:00.000Z","Count":2},{"Group":"SAFTT","Date":"2017-04-21T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"OPS","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"VIEW","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},{"Group":"VIEW","Date":"2017-04-19T00:00:00.000Z","Count":3}]
```

I have tried to use the reduce method but seem to be doing something wrong.

```
var obj = {}

result.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!obj[e.Date]) {
    obj[e.Date] = {
      Date: e.Date,
      Assest: []
    }
    r.push(obj[e.Date])
  }
  obj[e.Date].Date.push(e.Group)
  obj[e.Date].Date.push(e.Count)
  return r
}, [])

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

My desired outcome would be:

```
Var New_Data = [{"Date":"xx/xx/xx", "Assets":[{"group":"XXX"},{"Count":"X"}]},{"Date":"xx/xx/xx","Assets":[{"group":"XXX"},{"Count":"X"}]}]
```

Any Idea how I can achieve this, any help would be great. 
Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is a working example. With this in hand you should be able to alter it to your exact specifications, if they differ from what I have implemented.

```js
var Data = [
    {"Group":"OPS","Date":"2017-04-18T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"BOE","Date":"2017-04-19T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"EDW","Date":"2017-04-21T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"SUPPORT","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"EDWEXTRACTS","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"EDWEXTRACTS","Date":"2017-04-18T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"SAFTT","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"SAFTT","Date":"2017-04-18T00:00:00.000Z","Count":2},
    {"Group":"SAFTT","Date":"2017-04-21T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"OPS","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"VIEW","Date":"2017-04-17T00:00:00.000Z","Count":1},
    {"Group":"VIEW","Date":"2017-04-19T00:00:00.000Z","Count":3}
];

Data = Data.reduce(function(r, e) {
    var date = e.Date.match(/(\d+-\d+-\d+)/)[0].replace(/-/g, '/');

    if (r[date] == undefined) {
        r[date] = {Date: date, Assets: []};
    }
    
    r[date].Assets.push({Group: e.Group});
    r[date].Assets.push({Count: e.Count});
    
    return r
}, {});

console.log(Data);
```

You may need to convert the resulting object into an array:

```
new_data = [];
for(i in Data){
    new_data.push(Data[i]);
}
```

Comment: I was looking to keep only unique dates.
How would I go about doing that ?

Comment: I'll update my answer. Please be complete when posting a question.

Comment: Thank you, Sorry for not posting a complete question, it's my first time

Comment: That worked perfect for my project, I just adjusted the output to suit my needs. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like this?

```
var result = dados.map(function (v) {
    return {
        Date: new Date(v["Date"]),
        Assets: [
            {Group: v['Group']},
            {Count: v['Count']}
        ]
    };
});
```

or Do you need to create a group?